# Session is saving only records and it's not saving the rest of the records in PHP?

Tags: php, session, variables

```
function  mycart($mydate=null,$day=null)
 {
  $mycart= $this->session->userdata('mycart');
  $totalprice=$this->session->userdata('totalprice');

    if($this->limitation($mydate) && (!(isset($mycart[$mydate]))) )
    {          
     $mycart[$mydate] = array(
     'meal' =>$this->session->userdata('meal'),
     'day' =>$day,
     'date' =>$mydate,
     'disable'=>FALSE,
     'flag'=>null);
     $this->session->set_userdata('mycart',$mycart);  

     $this->session->set_userdata('totalprice',$totalprice);
    }// end  of if        

 }//  end  of  function
```

I am saving an array called `$mycart` in session but only 10 carts, i.e, only 10 records are getting saved after which 11th one is not getting saved in session. The session only save 10 array element can any one tell me why??

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is irrelevant to the problem you describe.

Try creating code from scratch to replicate the issue.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your issue is with your array itself.  If you have two carts with the same `$mydate` value, the latter will override the first value.  You need to use a multidimensional array in this case, i.e.:

```
$mycart[$mydate][] = array(
     'meal' =>$this->session->userdata('meal'),
     'day' =>$day,
     'date' =>$mydate,
     'disable'=>FALSE,
     'flag'=>null);
```

Otherwise you may perhaps be skipping with your first check on `isset($mycart[$mydate])`, which would essentially skip over an entire cart.

Comment: No same  carts  are not  getting  stored I  checked with that possibility .The (!(isset($mycart[$mydate])))  condition  doesnt  allow  to add other cart  with same key  name.I before 11th records  everything is working fine.But after 10  carts  are  saved in session its   just  not  saving the  11th one.Is  there limitation on the  number  of items  we save in session???do  i need to do  some  kind  of  settings.